# Aplicação C# não carrega arquivo XML ao por a aplicação pra iniciar com o Windows

Tags: c#, xml, windows

Tenho um aplicativo que lê um arquivo XML ao ser aberto, feito isso manualmente dá certo, más se por a aplicação pra iniciar com o windows o mesmo não lê o arquivo.

Comment: Não entendi nada, coloque mais detalhes sobre o problema, seja mais preciso no problema (está com cara que nem é bem o que você está escrevendo), as circunstâncias, coloque seu código.

Comment: Queria apenas que entendesse o seguinte bigown, quando dou dois cliques ele abre a aplicação e lê o XML e seta os textos em textbox, tem uma configuração que ao estar marcada inicia com o windows, mas quando inicia com o windows e abro a aplicação os campos estão em branco, compreendeu agora?

Comment: Não porque você não colocou informação nova. Da maneira como está temos que adivinhar como você está fazendo tudo isto. Entenda que você conhece sua aplicação, nós não. Se você não detalhar as partes relevantes para o seu problema de como ela funciona, não tem como ajudá-lo. Eu entendi o problema, não dá para entender o que você está fazendo na sua aplicação. Pode ser infinitas coisas. Pode ser só um problema de permissão/autorização, pode ser que seu código esteja fazendo coisas de forma errada que funciona por coincidência em determinada situação, entre outras coisas.

Comment: Pode ser o facto do programa não encontrar o caminho do ficheiro por exemplo, quando inicia com duplo clique o caminho que indicou funciona, mas quando o windows inicia o programa, o caminho já não aponta para o sitio certo (esta a usar caminhos relativos para o ficheiro?)

Comment: O proprio windows se encarrega disto Ommi, quando vou no msconfig.exe e vejo os programas que iniciam com o windows ele está lá, clico na opção "abrir local do arquivo" e ele exibe exatamente no local que esta o XML, a extensão esta .xml será que teria que fazer na .config?

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues volto a perguntar, que tipo de caminho esta a utilizar? Relativo ou absoluto? Mesmo antes do sitio onde le o arquivo XML, imprima o caminho para um ficheiro e confirme que esta correto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o XML estiver no mesmo local onde está seu executável, use o código:

```
string caminho = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "\\arquivo.xml");
```